# Xcode app on Simulator works, on real device crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a strange problem, whenever i run my app on the iPad simulator it works perfectly but if i try on a real device (iPad air iOS 7.0.4) it crashes while attempting this piece of code.

I have :

Nav controller embedded in a master detail split view controller (will call A) -> replace segue ->

uitableViewController -> replace segue ->

someViewController (will call B)

and now.. replace segue back to the Nav Controller (all are master detail) and here it crashed on the real device giving only: (lldb)

now this is B implementation

```
- (IBAction)backToTable:(id)sender
{
    id detail = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];
    if(detail) { // iPad
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToTable" sender:self];
    }
    else       // iPhone
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"backToTable"]){
        ViewControllerA *destViewController = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        destViewController.boolForSegue = @"true";
    }
}
```

and this is A

```
.h
@property (strong) NSString *boolForSegue;

.m

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([_boolForSegue isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        [self unlockView];
    }
}

- (void)unlockView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

I repeat that on simulator works perfectly no issue at all. What could be the problem??

EDIT:

```
crash log
Date/Time:           2014-02-06 23:00:34.420 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000153edbeb8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001908879d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x00000001873fb09c -[UISearchBar willMoveToSuperview:] + 64
2   UIKit                           0x00000001875d4ea0 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 188
3   UIKit                           0x00000001873043f0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 68
4   UIKit                           0x00000001873074f8 -[UIView dealloc] + 420
5   UIKit                           0x00000001873eb350 -[UIScrollView dealloc] + 968
6   UIKit                           0x00000001874abc3c -[UITableView dealloc] + 1300
7   UIKit                           0x000000018749c108 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 460
8   UIKit                           0x00000001875205f8 -[UITableViewController dealloc] + 288
9   UIKit                           0x000000018782cdc4 -[UIStoryboardSegue dealloc] + 68
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001908893d0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 520
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018433589c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
12  UIKit                           0x00000001872fde34 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 72
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f77dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f4a64 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f4df0 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184335b34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
17  GraphicsServices                0x0000000189d1782c GSEventRunModal + 164
18  UIKit                           0x00000001873740e4 UIApplicationMain + 1152
19  MasterSecurity                  0x000000010006f688 main (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000190e77a9c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190f59ac8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190e5dd74 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190f72e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190ff17a4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000190f72e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000190ff17a4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001701669c0   x1: 0x000000018798d5a1   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000191a40750   x9: 0x0000000153edbea8  x10: 0x000011d61ce68cd1  x11: 0x000000050000000f
   x12: 0x00000001703e35e0  x13: 0xbaddd0ad53edbead  x14: 0x000000000000004c  x15: 0x0000000170036440
   x16: 0x00000001908879c0  x17: 0x00000001908a1b6c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000012450fdc0
   x20: 0x0000000124846a00  x21: 0x0000000191a7f000  x22: 0x0000000124846a00  x23: 0x0000000191a83000
   x24: 0x000000000000001e  x25: 0x000000018798df25  x26: 0x0000000124513b40  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000191ac3550  fp: 0x000000016fda21c0   lr: 0x00000001873fb1d0
    sp: 0x000000016fda21a0   pc: 0x00000001908879d0 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint added? If so, what line is it stopping execution on? Also, if you click continue until the program closes, what error gets spit out at that point?

Comment: @Gavin no breakpoints

Comment: @pawan should i find the logs in the organizer?

Comment: The fact that you say the debugger shows "(lldb)" implies that the debugger is stopping program execution. So try hitting continue, because otherwise it might be stopping it before it actually generates a crash log or even displays the reason for the crash.

Comment: no in xcode terminal, at bottom. you should get the crash log. while debugging on device.

Comment: @pawan it gives me only (lldb) :)

Comment: @Gavin how to hit "continue"?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd You can either hit continue from the buttons that appear in the little bar right above the debugger output, or you can choose continue from the "Debug" menu.

Comment: @Gavin yeah i found 2 secs ago :) anyway nothing happens, still on (lldb), but why on simulator would work perfectly?

Comment: yes, you are on break point. @Gavin is right.

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Are you still at a breakpoint? Sometimes you need to do it a few times. You should do it until it no longer gives you "Continue" as an option.

Comment: @Gavin hit 100 times, still on (lldb), but if it was a breakpoint why on simulator works?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Kill the app in Xcode, then launch the app from the device itself (so no debugger is connected) and see if it works or still fails. If it fails/crashes, then go to the Organizer in Xcode and look at the console log for your device to see if it mentions some reason for a crash. If not, look and see if there is a crash log.

Comment: @Gavin yeah it shows a crash log in the organizer

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Look at the time on it. Assuming its from the crash just now, add the crash log to your answer. You may also possibly need to paste some of the relevant lines of code depending on what it says.

Comment: @Gavin then are binary images need them too?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have an uninitialized variable or a "zombie" problem you can get different behaviors in different environments.  Probably it would be a good idea to run Analyzer and also run the app with Zombies.

Comment: Seems fishy. Do you really have a property called `boolForSegue`? And if yes, why is it a string?

Comment: @Caleb yep VC A in .h.. But not synthesized in .m could this be?

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd In seeing where it said your crash was, I took another look at your code and posted an answer that is almost certainly the reason for your crash.

Comment: @Gavin the crash log is almost the same even after changing to viewDidAppear

Comment: Are you using Core Data at all? Do you have a core data data model?

Comment: @doc92606 yep man, but everything works fine on iPhone(simulator / real) and in iPad (simulator only), just crashes in real device.. anyway i suppose the problem is when i try to use the replace segue because it crashes just after the view did load of ViewController B. So i just switched to push segue and it worked..don't ask me why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your A implementation, in `viewWillAppear:` (before the view controller has finished appearing) you're calling a method that calls `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, which will try to display another view controller. You have to wait until the first segue has finished first. So if you move that call to `viewDidAppear:` instead, it will fix your problem.

Remember, don't try to display a view controller while another one is still in the process of being displayed.

Comment: i changed to viewDidAppear but it's still crashing!! :( same problem and also continue in debugger doesn't work

Comment: Write here too, i put some logs and saw the app crashed just after the viewDidLoad of VC B, apparently with no reasons as there was no method running in any thread because were all IBActions and delegate methods for a picker view that loaded without any problem. So the only thing could be the replace segue from a tableVC (navigation bar item, not row) to VC B, i tried to replace it with a push segue and i worked perfectly on the real iPad. Can't still figure out why. Thanks anyway for your help Gavin